# Can we force a Generic type to accept its parameterized type as only concrete child subclasses of a type and not that type itself

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

```
class Team<E extends Player> {
    E player1;
    E player2;
}

abstract class Player{
}

class CricketPlayer extends Player{}
class BaseballPlayer extends Player{}
class FootballPlayer extends Player{}
```

I understand now i can create teams as follows which have the same type of players and it would work

```
Team<CricketPlayer> cricketTeam = new Team<>()

Team<BaseballPlayer> baseballTeam = new Team<>()
```

But someone can also create a team as follows

```
Team<Player> invalidTeam = new Team<>();
```

In this case, `player1` can be set as `FootballPlayer` and `player2` can be set as `CricketPlayer`, because both extend from the Player class. So the two players in a team are of different type now.The purpose got defeated, where i wanted a Team to have same type of players. Is there a way to achieve this. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: To my knowledge, no, there's not (or at least, no in a conventional way). Most probably you'll get a runtime exception, which is expected.

Comment: No, there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve it with such hierarchy.

Although you can use next method inside `Team<E extends Player>` to check compatibility with a previous value:

```
public void setPlayer2(E player2) {
    Class<? extends Player> player1Class = player1.getClass();
    Class<? extends Player> player2Class = player2.getClass();
    if (player1Class.getSimpleName() != player2Class.getSimpleName()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect type for player2!");
    }
    this.player2 = player2;
}
```

This would complicate the maintainability.

So, why can't you use only `Team<BaseballPlayer>` or `Team<BaseballPlayer>` to limit the type inside?

Comment: Yes, i can do it. But i have a team of developers, and i was wondering if there is a mechanism to restrict it through the api itself

Comment: If I had to restrict the type of a player inside a class I would use `Team<CricketPlayer>` or `Team<BaseballPlayer>`. I think it's easier.